# 'sudo apt-get update' get a warning

Tags: apt, updates

Ubuntu 16.4, running 'sudo apt-get update'  this line shows up last

N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'http://dl.google.com/linux/earth/deb stable InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'

Is there a way to fix this?

There was an older version of Google Earth on this PC, when it was being used as 32bit. Switched over to 64bit and Google Earth runs well, but noticed this error (if it really is an error) doing updates.

Comment: It's just a notification - don't worry about it. I was able to disable this message by adding `[ arch = amd64 ]` in the Google Earth repo, but it's overwritten whenever it's upgraded.

Comment: For the accepted answer... You also need to edit `/etc/cron.daily/google-earth-pro` and edit the line `REPOCONFIG="deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/earth/deb/ stable main"` to include the `[arch=amd64]`, otherwise your edits will be overwritten.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's just a warning message you can disregard.  This said, if you WANT to fix the issue...

> NOTE: All commands specified for "go into" or "run" are to be run in the Command Line.

Go into your `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` folder.  Run `grep -r 'dl.google.com'` and it will show you which file(s) contain that string.

Edit each of those files (with `sudo` before your chosen text editor on the command line) and where you see `deb` at the beginning of the lines replace that with `deb [arch=amd64]` so that your strings look like:

```
deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/earth/deb stable main
```

Then run `sudo apt-get update` again.  It should then cease with the warnings.

You will also need to edit `/etc/cron.daily/google-earth-pro` and edit the line `REPOCONFIG="deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/earth/deb stable main"` otherwise it won't work and will overwrite things.  (Thanks to [heynnema](https://askubuntu.com/users/4272/heynnema) for that info.)

Comment: You also need to edit `/etc/cron.daily/google-earth-pro` and edit the line `REPOCONFIG="deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/earth/deb/ stable main"` to include the `[arch=amd64]`, otherwise your edits will be overwritten.